# How to Retrieve Text Input entered value on Button Click onPress in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native,and I cannot retrieve which I entered on textInput as one by one..

Example: If i Entered some names, It Should appear one by one...

```
  state = {
    name: "",
    showName: false
  };

  buttonClickListner = e => {
    const { showName } = this.state;

    this.setState({ showName: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;
    return (
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 150 }}
          placeholder="Enter a Name...."
          value={name}
          onChangeText={val => {
            this.setState({
              name: val
            });
          }}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.buttonClickListner}
          title="Submit"
          color="#008000"
        />
        <Text>{(showName = true ? name : null)}</Text>    
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: One by one means??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done what you need. You need a sequence of name whatever you type in that TextInput but using string it's not possible. You need to take an array to display all the values that you're going to enter.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
    name: [],
    showName: false,
    text:""
  };

  buttonClickListner = e => {
    this.state.name.push( this.state.text.toString() );
    this.setState({text:""})
  };
  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 150 }}
          placeholder="Enter a Name...."
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={val => {
            this.setState({
              text: val
            });
          }}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.buttonClickListner}
          title="Submit"
          color="#008000"
        />
        {this.state.name.length>0?this.state.name.map(item=>(<Text>{item}</Text>)):null} 
        </View>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points that I see:

- First of all, you should return a **single root from your return** or multiple elements with fragments(read fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)). So wrapped them all in some single tag like //your components  etc.
- You are assigning in your `showName = true` instead of checking. Use **`showName === true`** ? syntax.

And the complete code and [runnig sample](https://snack.expo.io/@cmlonder/textinput-example):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
      name: "",
      showName: false
    };

  buttonClickListner = e => {
    const { showName } = this.state;
    this.setState({ showName: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, showName } = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 150 }}
            placeholder="Enter a Name...."
            value={name}
            onChangeText={val => {
              this.setState({
                name: val
              });
            }}
          />
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListner}
            title="Submit"
            color="#008000"
          />
          <Text>{(showName === true ? name : null)}</Text>   
        </View> 
      );
  }
}
```